# Stripe full redirect method Change back button text currently showing site domain

Tags: stripe-payments

I am trying to create api where different sites will use our api which will generate a token and they will use that token to redirect the user

I am using this code

```
$checkout_session = \Stripe\Checkout\Session::create([

  'customer_email' => $customer_email,
  'payment_method_types' => ['card'],
  'line_items' => [[
    'price_data' => [
      'currency' => 'dkk',
      'unit_amount' => $course_price,
      'product_data' => [
        'name' => $course_title,
        'images' => [$course_image],
      ],
    ],
    'quantity' => 1,
  ]],
  
  

  'mode' => 'payment',
  'success_url' => $success_url,
  'cancel_url' => $cancel_url,

]);
```

I want to make the back button dynamic is it possible?

[image: img_backButton]

Comment: That button should use the value of `cancel_url`, so set it to anything you like.

Comment: it is not using cancel_url
it actually redirect me to cancel_url but show domain name see image attached on descriotion

Comment: The URL at the bottom of your image is unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. The Checkout Session is created using your account's public key. So naturally, the "back" button on the Checkout page will show your domain.

What you can change however, is the text of the payment button (although not as flexible as you'd wish): https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-submit_type

Answer (score 0):

Changing the name for a single account is not possible as it was in the old stripe version. But in the Stripe session checkout, if you are having multiple connected accounts, you can change the **Public business name** (if you have access, otherwise ask account owner) to whatever the business wants from the stripe portal https://dashboard.stripe.com/settings/account.